# Keep data refreshed in Power BI Service when a dataset uses an R script

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a pbix file that imports a dataset from an R package (in Power Query).

It works well, but I can't keep this dataset refreshed on Power BI Service.

Data flows do not support R scripts.

Using my personal data gateway, I get the following error in the data source credentials:

[image]

Is there any solution for this problem, or is R incompatible as a data source for Power BI Service?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this official [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-r-in-query-editor) and make sure that:

1. Update the gateway
2. R is installed in the Personal Data Gateway
3. R data source is set to public

If both are OK, there was a guy with your exact same issue. Please refer to this [article](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Refresh-R-Scripts-with-Personal-Gateway/m-p/434099#M17624) which contains an official Microsoft response.

Comment: thanks for helping, It turned out nothing you suggested worked. However, I've installed the latest version of the gateway and now it refreshes the R script!

Comment: You are right, I missed the Step 0: update the gateway :P